# How can I cast an expression from type interface, to an specific type

Tags: c#, interface, lambda, type-conversion, expression

In my interface I have following defined

```
List<IFoo> GetListOfFoo<T>(Expression<Func<T, bool>> predicate) where T : IFoo;
```

In my implementation I'll cast the expression in the specific type:

```
if (typeof(T) == typeof(Foo))
{
    Expression converted = Expression.Convert(predicate.Body, typeof(Foo));
    Expression<Func<Foo, bool>> newPredicate = 
        Expression.Lambda<Func<Foo, bool>>(converted, predicate.Parameters);
}
```

I try to use my implementation like this:

```
Expression<Func<Foo, bool>> predicate = c => c.Name == "Myname";
_repository.GetListOfFoo<Foo>(predicate);
```

I get no compiling errors, but if I use this, I get an Exception that in the ExpressionBody is the bool argument defined.

Where is my problem?

Comment: What exactly does the exception say?

Comment: @SLaks - It throws an exception not an error.  Please post more details Mario.

Comment: The if for type checking is not required because of your where clause

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a better solution. I don't need to cast the predicate themselves.

```
public List<IFoo> GetFoos<T>(Expression<Func<T, bool>> predicate) where T : class, IModel 
{
    var result = new List<IFoo>();
    var repository = new Repository<T>();
    result.AddRange(repository.GetEntities(predicate).ToList().ConvertAll(c => (IFoo)c));
    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code doesn't make any sense.

You're creating an `Expression.Convert` that returns a `Foo`, then trying to use that as a function that returns a `bool`.

The `Expression.Convert` also doesn't make sense; you can't convert a `bool` to a `Foo`.

You're probably trying to write

```
var converted = (Expression<Func<Foo, bool>>) predicate;
```

As long as `T` is `Foo`, this will work fine.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I don't want convert a bool to a Foo, but a Foo in a IFoo, because Foo implements IFoo. In my further Methodbody I work with the interface

Comment: In other words, you want to walk the expression tree and replace any reference to the parameter with a cast.  You need to write an ExpressionVisitor.

Answer (score 0):

The parameter's type need to change, not the body of the expression.

Upon invocation from your implementation, you would have to do the conversion.

Also does not make sense why you need this as `Foo : IFoo`.