# Common filtering logic in WCF query interceptors using interface

Tags: c#, linq, wcf, interface, expression

The classes in my data model implement an interface:

```
public class SomeType : ISomeInterface

public interface ISomeInterface
```

In my WCF query interceptors, I want to use a common `Expression` so that I can use the same filtering logic on multiple types:

```
[QueryInterceptor("SomeType")]
public Expression<Func<SomeType, bool>> SomeTypeInterceptor()
{
    // Return CommonFilter() or extend it with logic unique to SomeType
}

private Expression<Func<ISomeInterface, bool>> CommonFilter()
{
    // Use ISomeInterface methods and properties to build expression
    // ...
}
```

The problem is getting the `Expression<Func<SomeType, bool>>` to get along with the `Expression<Func<ISomeInterface, bool>>`.

**Attempt #1**

Just returning the common expression does not compile:

```
[QueryInterceptor("SomeType")]
public Expression<Func<SomeType, bool>> SomeTypeInterceptor()
{
    return CommonFilter();
}
```

with the error:

> Cannot implicitly convert type `System.Linq.Expressions.Expression<System.Func<ISomeInterface, bool>>` to `System.Linq.Expressions.Expression<System.Func<SomeType, bool>>`

**Attempt #2**

Using the interface in the query interceptor definition:

```
[QueryInterceptor("SomeType")]
public Expression<Func<ISomeInterface, bool>> SomeTypeInterceptor()
```

compiles, but WCF does not like this, returning an error to the client:

> Return type of method 'SomeTypeInterceptor' on type 'DataService' is of type `System.Linq.Expressions.Expression<System.Func<ISomeInterface, System.Boolean>>` but a type assignable to `System.Linq.Expressions.Expression<System.Func<SomeType, System.Boolean>>` is required for a query interceptor.

**Attempt #3**

Looking at the questions [How can I cast an expression from type interface, to an specific type](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10819306/3271599) and [C# How to convert an `Expression<Func<SomeType>>` to an `Expression<Func<OtherType>>`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/654153/3271599), I tried implementing [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10299730/3271599):

```
[QueryInterceptor("SomeType")]
public Expression<Func<SomeType, bool>> SomeTypeInterceptor()
{
    Expression<Func<SomeType, bool>> someTypeExpression =
        someType => CommonFilter().Compile().Invoke(someType);

    return someTypeExpression;
}
```

but now LINQ to Entities does not like this, returning an error:

> LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'Boolean Invoke(ISomeInterface)' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression.

---

Is there a way to use common logic in WCF query interceptors?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make the `CommonFilter` method generic with required interface constraint on the generic type argument plus `class` constraint (needed by LINQ to Entities):

```
private Expression<Func<T, bool>> CommonFilter<T>()
    where T : class, ISomeInterface
{
    // Use ISomeInterface methods and properties to build expression
    // ...
}
```

Then use a slightly modified version of your *Attempt #1* (which does compile):

```
[QueryInterceptor("SomeType")]
public Expression<Func<SomeType, bool>> SomeTypeInterceptor()
{
    return CommonFilter<SomeType>();
}
```